# Check for pattern in a string in VBA

Tags: vba

My requirement is that I need to check whether a string variable has first character "P" followed by digits.

For example

> P0
>    P123
>    P22

To-date I have looked at options for using `Like` as per [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te33kb6t.aspx).

Comment: Yes i did , I verified msdn link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te33kb6t.aspx .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a simple RegExp:

```
Function strOut(strIn As String) As String
    Dim objRegex As Object
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Pattern = "^P\d+$"
        strOut = .Test(strIn)
    End With
End Function
```

*test code*

```
Sub Test()
Debug.Print strOut("P22")
Debug.Print strOut("aP22")
Debug.Print strOut("P12344")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the native `Like` operator:

```
Sub Foo()

Dim x As String, matches As Boolean
x = "P123"

matches = (x Like "P" & Application.Rept("[0-9]", Len(x) - 1))

Debug.Print matches

End Sub
```

Comment: REPT and LEN a clever way to avoid multiple LIKE tests

Answer (score 1):

```
(mystr Like "P#") or (mystr Like "P##") or (mystr Like "P###")
```

is probably the fastest solution, and the simplest one.

```
mystr like left("P######", len(mystr))
```

could work as well, and be more generic.

Anyway, if this is to be used in a query, a generic `LIKE` should be much more efficient than any VBA function.

Answer (score 0):

my 0.02 cents

```
Sub Foo2()
x = "P0123"
Debug.Print IsNumeric(Replace(x, "P", "",,1))
End Sub
```

Comment: I actually assumed that "P" would always be the first character. Were it not, it must be changed to `IsNumeric(Right(x, Len(x) - 1))`